# Calling a script from wxpython and sending user input data during the run

Tags: wxpython

I am writing a GUI for a quadrotor simulator using wxpython. I am trying to call my main program with a button click which calls the script main.py sending some initial data, while keeping the GUI responsive and send user input data to the main script. Is there a simple way to achieve this without sending information through socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to communicate between two separate scripts, then a socket server would be one of the easiest ways to go. I wrote up a tutorial on this topic fairly recently here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/06/27/wxpython-how-to-communicate-with-your-gui-via-sockets/

You could use other server backends if you need something more robust. If you want to get really advanced, then you might want to look at RabbitMQ, but I think that's overkill for this project.